# Error when executing a stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which is failing while inserting the data from one table to another table.
The error is

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'ExtpndPart1' with unique index 'IDX_Primary'

I know this error comes when the destination table has a primary key on a particular column and the source table has duplicates in that column.
but i hv a condition which drops the primary key in the stored procedure.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysindexes WHERE name  =  N'PK_ExtpndPart1' )
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExtpndPart1] DROP [PK_ExtpndPart1]
```

Can any one help me??

Comment: do you wish to insert the duplicate? or do you wish to remove duplicates before attempting the insert?

Comment: Why have the unique index at all if inserting duplicates?

Comment: The table has a primary key and Index, the stored procedure is dropping the PK but not the index so it is throwing an error, but actually there are no duplicates in the source table......but still getting an error bcoz of the index, but i want the index to be there:(

Comment: It sounds like you maybe want to do a merge on the destination table? i.e. perform an INSERT where the unique key doesn't exist and UPDATE when it does? There's a statement for that in SQL Server (2008): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for/dropping the wrong index. You're dropping `PK_ExtpndPart1` but the error refers to `IDX_Primary`.

Comment: The table has a primary key and Index, the stored procedure is dropping the PK but not the index so it is throwing an error, but actually there are no duplicates in the source table......but still getting an error bcoz of the index, but i want the index to be there:(

Comment: @ramesh: If I've got this right then, there are no duplicates in the source table, but the row could already exist in the destination table? What would you expect to happen in that case?

Comment: the second table or the destination table is truncated before inserting the data from source –

Comment: @ramesh: Can you show script/post the create statement for the index in question?

Comment: @ramesh: The *index* is huge and confidential?

Comment: @Joe Thank You. I solved this by removing the unique clustered index, as all the data is valid and cannot be neglected by selecting distinct because each column for a single record may match with another record(which are duplicates) buy have some columns which are different

Comment: @ramesh: That's what I suspected when I was asking to see the index definition. Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to drop index `PK_ExtpndPart1`, but the offending index is `IDX_Primary`.

Comment: The table has a primary key and Index, the stored procedure is dropping the PK but not the index so it is throwing an error, but actually there are no duplicates in the source table......but still getting an error bcoz of the index, but i want the index to be there:(

Comment: Are there duplicates in the second table?  It sounds as if at least one of the key values overlap in the two tables.

Comment: the second table or the destination table is truncated before inserting the data from source

Answer (score 0):

Either you or your server are clearly in the wrong. If you are right and there can be no attempts at inserting duplicates which would violate `IDX_Primary`, then it's your server's fault, obviously.

Otherwise you might just have overlooked the fact that the duplicates somehow are really there. Either they are in the source table, or the destination table is not being properly truncated.

It's all right that you are not willing to share confidential code, but then we have little information beside what you have revealed.

Anyway, I'm backing up what you have already been told: the offended index is `IDX_Primary`, not `PK_ExtpndPart1`. So what do you do? First, find the script that creates `IDX_Primary` and pay attention to the index expression/expressions. Having done that, just use the expression(s) in a simple query on your source table to find out if there are indeed no duplicates.

I think you could easily come up with some script of that sort, but just because I do not see how else I can help you in the lack of details I've decided to share with you this little template of mine:

```
SELECT
  ..., /* column(s) or expression(s) as used in IDX_Primary
         (actually, their counterparts in the source table) */
  COUNT(*)
FROM ... /* your source table */
GROUP BY ... /* the same IDX_Primary column(s) or expression(s) */
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

As you can see, the result would be the very duplicates which are sure to upset `IDX_Primary`.

Comment: I solved this by removing the unique clustered index, as all the data is valid and cannot be neglected by selecting distinct because each column for a single record may match with another record(which are duplicates) buy have some columns which are different.